Raydium SDK v2 showing no liquidity in clmm position when there is liquidity
Using Raydium's SDK v2, I opened a clmm liquidity pool position. I'm running into an issue when trying to close the position using closePosition.ts. It keeps failing. It still produced a tx id, which using solana explorer tx inspector, I saw it says the position has no liquidity. When I use fetchPositionInfo.ts or when I manually check the wallet on Raydium's website, it clearly shows their is liquidity and rewards. The error I keep running into with closePosition.ts is:
UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "undefined".
    at throwUnhandledRejectionsMode (node:internal/process/promises:392:7)
    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:475:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:106:32) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'

Anyone come across this before?

Can you share these details, for example, the pool, the failed txId and the closePosition.ts snippet?

the poolid is BZtgQEyS6eXUXicYPHecYQ7PybqodXQMvkjUbP4R8mUU and the [https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/blob/master/src/clmm/closePosition.ts], sorry I lost the tx id. I read through more of the sdk docs and I think the closeposition transaction isn't going through because of no priority fees being included
